# How to make readInt() block on input byte stream?

Tags: java, exception, tcp, network-programming, stream

I have an input stream coming form a blackbox (say B). All the messages coming in from this stream are serialized binary data and each message starts with a four byte int. Most of it is logging data and runs 24 hrs a day. I read these four bytes using readInt() method. Now, ocasionally, the main thread would exit with EOFException and crash the program.

After researching on this, I found that it happens when there are less than four bytes in the input stream at the time of readInt(). My guess is that the buffer is not filling in fast enough between successive reads. Some of the possible solutions I am thinking of include checking available() before reading (consumes too many cycles considering the amt of data) or restart when exception occurs (sounds like poor programing). If only I could block using readInt(), it would be the best way, I think. I've looked at implementation of readInt() but again it boils down to blocking with read().

Anyone knows of a better solution?

Comment: You seem to be blocking the reading-flow by producing a wall-of-text ;-) Introducing some paragraphs might make this more readable (and will help get answers).

Comment: What kind of stream are you reading from?

Comment: You have a point there Joachim. I'll be more careful. I am using DataInputStream as Stas guessed.Having an embedded device on the other end makes it difficult to change stuff there. My guess is that the blackbox may be sending intermitten chunks of bytes not caring wether the message is sen in entirity. The stream may go dry at times without having complete contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any blocking call down the call hierarchy is "bound" to make all the calls up the chain blocking as along as both calls are part of same thread of execution. The `readInt` method of `DataInputStream` makes four calls to the `read` method of the underlying input stream which will surely block as long as the data is not made available hence your fear of "buffer doesn't fill in fast enough" doesn't seem to be logical.

I have encountered these kind of exceptions in cases where either the server process dies or or drops the connection in which case the client ends up reading a -1 and throws an exception. Are you gobbling any sort of exceptions in your client/server code? Do your logs show anything suspicious?

Comment: You are right about the blocking. The server in my case is an embedded device that might sent intermitten chunks of data. When things aren't available on the stream, read() returns -1 and readInt() returns EOFException. This is expected behavior. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: It can be assumed that the data will never stop flowing and I am not worried about closing the stream. So for practical purpose it can be assumed that the connection is never closed on the server side and an actual end of stream is never reached.

Comment: Like already mentioned, there is no "when things aren't available on the stream" since the client would "wait" for that as long as the server doesn't decide to return -1. Since this data from the server is stream and flows in chunks, have you made sure that you have an appropriate timeout set for your client/server socket?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are using DataInputStream. That class throws EOFException in situation when the stream which it wraps,  returns -1 from the read() method (which actually blocks until input data is available).

I suppose, you should have a look why the main stream's read returns with -1 in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The basic [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) interface requires blocking reads, the EOFException you get is thrown when the readInt() encounters the end of stream marker, since returning the incomplete int would be a bad idea it throws the **E**nd **O**f **F**ile Exception.

The [EOFException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) is thrown because the other end of the stream reached its end,has been closed or is no longer connected. You should check if the blackbox terminates the connection.

Since the stream is network based your socket may have a timeout set, if this is the case try changing the [SOTimeout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) value of the socket.

Comment: The black box is an embedded device and may send intermittent chunks of data. This may cause only <4 bytes at the other end and not send anyhing for a while. I am looking to block till all 4 bytes are received. SOTimeout is a good idea. I'll look into it right now and see if that helps.